# c# 3.0 Casting an interfaced generic type

Tags: c#, generics, casting, c#-3.0

Given these base classes and interfaces

```
public abstract class Statistic : Entity, IStatistic
{
  protected abstract IStatisticsRepository<IStatistic> Repository {get;}

...

public class AverageCheckTime : Statistic

...

public interface IStatisticsRepository<T> : IRepository<T>  where T : IStatistic

...

public interface IAverageCheckTimeRepository : IStatisticsRepository<AverageCheckTime>

...

public class AverageCheckTimeRepository : StatisticRepository<AverageCheckTime>, IAverageCheckTimeRepository

...

public class RepositoryFactory
{
   public static IAverageQueueTimeRepository AverageQueueTimeRepository 
    {
      get { return CurrentServiceLocator.GetInstance<IAverageQueueTimeRepository>(); }
    }
```

Why does AverageCheckTime's implementation throw an invalid cast exception:

```
protected override IStatisticsRepository<IStatistic> Repository
    {
      get { return (IStatisticsRepository<IStatistic>)RepositoryFactory.AverageCheckTimeRepository; }
    }
```

How do I cast an instance of `IAverageCheckTimeRepository` as an `IStatisticsRepository<IStatistic>` which I assumed it already was?

---

OK, I've made these changes...which makes me wonder if I've gone over the top with the generics in the first place

```
    public interface IStatisticsHelper
      {
        void GenerateStatistics();

        List<IStatistic> BuildReport();
      }

...

    public interface IStatisticsRepository<T> : IRepository<T>, IStatisticsHelper where T : IStatistic
      {

      }

...

    public abstract class Statistic : Entity, IStatistic
      {

        protected abstract IStatisticsHelper Repository { get; }

    ...

public class AverageCheckTime : Statistic
  {
    protected override IStatisticsHelper Repository
    {
      get { return RepositoryFactory.AverageCheckTimeRepository; }
    }
```

Comment: Are you missing something because no where do I see that a `StatisticRepository<AverageCheckTime>` is a `IStatisticRepository<IStatistic>`

Comment: made that edit: public interface IStatisticsRepository<T> : IRepository<T>  where T : IStatistic

Comment: @BobTodd: Now we don't know what `IRepository<T>` looks like...

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/sharp-architecture/source/browse/trunk/src/SharpArch/SharpArch.Core/PersistenceSupport/IRepository.cs?spec=svn353&r=353

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, C# 3 does not support *generic variance*. C# 4 does, but you would have to declare that `IStatisticsRepository` is covariant in `T`:

```
public interface IStatististicsRepository<out T> : IRepository<T>
    where T : IStastistic
```

Variance isn't safe *in general* - it depends on how the generic type parameter is used. C# 4 supports both covariance and contravariance for type arguments which are reference types, but only when the generic type involved is an interface or a delegate, and only when the type parameter is used in the appropriate way within the interface/delegate.

Without seeing the declaration for `IRepository<T>`, we can't tell whether or not it's safe. For example, if `IRepository<T>` contains a method like this:

```
void Save(string id, T value);
```

then it *wouldn't* be safe, because you'd be able to write:

```
IStatisticsRepository<IStatistic> repo = RepositoryFactory.AverageCheckTimeRepository;
IStatistic foo = new SomeOtherStastisticType();
repo.Save("Foo", foo);
```

That would be trying to save a `SomeOtherStatisticType` value in an `AverageCheckTimeRepository`, which violates type safety. It's only safe to make the interface covariant in `T` if values of type `T` only come "out" of the interface. (There are some wrinkles around exactly what that means, mind you...)

For a lot more information on this, see Eric Lippert's [blog series on the topic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/covariance+and+contravariance/default.aspx).